# how to perform where and distinct count operation in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below sql query which has to be converted to equivalent pandas query to perform the same operation.

select COUNT (DISTINCT name) from students where age=12 and gender="M"

I tried using nunique() but don't know how to combine where condition.

Comment: len(df[(df.age == 12) & (df.gender == 'M')].name.unique())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different answers.  I like trying to offer a `pandas` and `numpy` oriented answer.  By no means am I implying these are ***the*** answers, just my take.

***`numpy`***
My solution.  Not canonical!

```
a = df.age.values == 12
g = df.gender.values == 'M'
len(np.unique(df.name.values[a & g]))
```

***`pandas`***
My solution.  Not canonical!

```
a = df.age.eq(12)
g = df.gender.eq('M')
df.name.loc[a & g].nunique()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use query or do boolean indexing and then get the count of unique items with `nunique`.

```
df.query('age == 12 & gender == "M"')['name'].nunique()
```